# Using lidR to count number of pulse returns at different intervals?

Tags: r, lidar, statistics, lidr, voxel

I am trying to get the number of pulse at different height interval.

I have used the `lidR` package to do this before with the code below but it seems that recent update in the package breaks my code. My main error is that when I run the function I get an error that says `the ScanAngle and PulseID no longer exist`. Any help on which function I should use now?

The following code used to work:

```
# the number of points is computed.
grid_metrics3d(lidar1, length(Z),res = 0.5)

# Cloud of points is voxelized with a 1-meter resolution and in each voxel
# the mean scan angle of points is computed.
grid_metrics3d(lidar1, mean(Angle),res = 0.5)

# Define your own metric function
myMetrics = function(i, ScanAngleRank, PointSourceID)
{
  ret = list(
   npulse  = length(unique(PointSourceID)),
   angle   = mean(ScanAngleRank),
   imean   = mean(i))

   return(ret)
}

voxels1 = grid_metrics3d(lidar1, myMetrics(Intensity, ScanAngle, PointID ),res = 0.5)
plot(voxels1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. You missed to compute the `pulseID` with `laspulse()` and you missed that the scan angle is stored in `ScanAngleRank`

Since `lidR 2.0.0` `pulseID` is no longer computed at read time. And since `rlas 1.3.0` that introduced support of LAS 1.4 format the attribute `ScanAngle` is now `ScanAngleRank`. The name `ScanAngle` is reserved for angle stored in LAS 1.4 format. This latest modification is known to break former codes like yours but was required to better fit with [LAS specifications](https://www.asprs.org/a/society/committees/standards/LAS_1_4_r13.pdf)

```
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)
las = laspulse(las)

myMetrics = function(I, A, ID)
{
  ret = list(
    npulse  = length(unique(ID)),
    angle   = mean(A),
    imean   = mean(I))

  return(ret)
}

voxels1 = grid_metrics3d(las, ~myMetrics(Z, ScanAngleRank, pulseID), res = 10)
plot(voxels1, "npulse")
```

Also notice that `PointSourceID` is not at all related to your question.  `PointSourceID` usually records an ID for each flightline